# Retry on timeout?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a Cucumber Scenario for testing UI features. Sometimes due to one of the several issues, web-page takes lot of time to respond and Capybara times out with following error.

```
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:146:in `rescue in rbuf_fill'
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rbuf_fill'
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
```

My question is-

Can I somehow force Cucumber scenario or `Capybara` to retry (for constant number of times) whole scenario or step respectively, on timeout error?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, you can do it like this:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  for i in 1..5
    begin
      block.call
      break
    rescue Timeout::Error
      next
    end
  end
end
```

But I can't figure out if this code works because of the bug ([It's not possible to call block several times in Around hook](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cukes/YsbX8QdDscg))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second answer to this post worked for me but I will keep this in mind.

Comment: +1 I swapped out Timeout::Error for just Exception.  Not sure why Timeout::Error was not catching it for me >.<

Comment: For some reason, with the Timeout::Error, it's still not caught.  Put in puts statements, and it only runs once, and fails once... oh the pain the pain of running capybara / selenium / webkit on this app!

Comment: For some reason, with the Timeout::Error, it's still not caught.  Put in puts statements, and it only runs once, and fails once... oh the pain the pain of running capybara / selenium / webkit on this app!

Answer (score 1):

From [The Cucumber book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book):

Add a `eventually method` that keeps trying to run a block of code until it  either stops raising an error or it reaches a time limit.

Here is the code for that method:

```
module AsyncSupport
  def eventually
    timeout = 2
    polling_interval = 0.1
    time_limit = Time.now + timeout
    loop do
      begin 
        yield
      rescue Exception => error
      end
      return if error.nil?
      raise error if Time.now >= time_limit sleep polling_interval
    end
  end
end
World(AsyncSupport)
```

The method called be called as follows from a step_definition:

```
Then /^the balance of my account should be (#{CAPTURE_CASH_AMOUNT})$/ do |amount|
  eventually { my_account.balance.should eq(amount) }
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This may have solved my problem. Not getting errors any more.